# Is it possible to display the text associated with a specific element?

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been working with selenium and C#, and I am wondering if I can return the text associated with a specific element.

For example, here is the line of HTML that contains what I want to display:

```
<span class="field">1149156-1</span>
```

Would it be possible to save the "1149156-1" in a string to use for later?

I have tried the following code, but it returns a strange value, definitely not the value I want it to return:

```
string testvariable = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]")).ToString();
```

Hope I provided enough information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `webElement.Text`.

```
string testvariable = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]")).Text;
```

On another note -- I recommend using relative XPath syntax instead of absolute, and querying on WebElement attributes such as `id`, `name`, and `class` to get more accurate locators.

For example, the XPath in the example you provided can be re-written more robustly as such:

```
//table[@id='someId']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much!